# Showing full-html (meta, head, body) in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I'm wondering if I can show a complete html-page to a user in a javascript popup.
By *complete html* I mean an html code with it's own encoding, head and body. It's own fonts, styles, scripts, etc...

Also, say that my "main" page has `utf8`. Is it possible the encoding of the popup content be something else? (note that I'm not asking how to decode from X and then encode to `utf8`, but actually showing another encoded content).

If that is not possible, what is the best way of showing a full html-page to an user without leaving the actual page?

Edit: Maybe going with the `iframe` method, but I'm not sure if I can write my html into the iframe.
Note that by the time I want to show the popup to the user, I already have the html data I want to show him, so I don't need to do any extra requests.

Edit:

Example (pseudo-code - javascript)

```
$(document.ready(){

    $.showPopup({
        content: "<!doctype html><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'><head></head><body>Hi!</body></html>";
    }):

});
```

Comment: What method do you want to open the popup with?

Comment: It doesn't matter at al, as far as it works. It can be plain js, jquery, kendo, dojo or whatever else you say for it to work.

Comment: You can open any page with `window.open();`, as a new tab using link with `target="_blank"` or in an `iframe`. Encoding doesn't matter. Each page can have different encoding.

Comment: @Michal As I already said in my question, I have the data I want to show to the user and I do not want to make any further requests to the server.

Comment: Could you post an example of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery to get the javascript object [0] and rewrite the entire content:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NrJap/1/

```
var target = $('#myiframe').contents()[0];
target.open();
target.write("<!doctype html><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'><head></head><body>Hi!</body></html>");
target.close();
```

Just incorporate that into a plugin/function for your $.popup

Comment: I have a problem with http://jsfiddle.net/NrJap/2/  <--- the popup shows the iframe, but there is no content inside it. Any ideas why could it be?

Answer (score 1):

You can write arbitrary HTML content into iframe like this:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
    iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document || iframe.contentDocument;

iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write(data);
iframeDoc.close();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jTcuK/1/

Answer (score -2):

to view plain html code you could simply alert it...

```
alert("<!doctype html><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'><head></head><body>Hi!</body></html>");
```

or you could use a view source button

http://css-tricks.com/make-a-view-source-button/

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewSourceButton/#

Comment: updated answer! I misunderstood you my friend. I thought you only needed to display the html for debugging or something similar, not client friendly.

Comment: You keep misreading what I'm asking about. I do not want to show the source code to the user nor show him an alert

Comment: no I get it :-), you have to use an iframe... like mentioned several times. I don't know if there are other options available, I doubt it.